# Where can I study ipython language?

Tags: ipython

In Korea, I think there are few people using ipython (not python).
So there are not useful information and community.

Now, I'm studying a book about data analysis (python for data analysis).

But it's hard to study ipython by oneself.
Where can I get the helpful information about ipython?

Comment: Welcome to so! -) If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/187716) for a full explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first off, it's still programming. -) You'll never get enough useful information or help from someone, but you will find it by yourself from books and docs.

second off, ipython isn't a language, it's a shell. So you can't actually learn like really a lot of it (*I guess?.. throw the brick into me if I'm wrong*), though you could (and you should) learn the things that you will need to work with.

have you tried going to ipython official resource? http://ipython.org/documentation.html# I guess there are enough manuals and helpful stuff about it.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. Your Answer is helpful

Comment: @Dongingang good luck! -) Feel free to ask.